# Install R packages in Fedora

Tags: r, fedora

I just started using R in Fedora 25, but could not install any packages in R GUI or RStudio. Take dplyr for example,

I got the the message as below:

```
The downloaded source packages are in 
'/tmp/RtmpM3VRo3/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html'...done
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages（“dplyr”）:
installation of package 'glue' had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages（“dplyr”）:
installation of package 'rlang' had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages（“dplyr”）:
installation of package 'Rcpp' had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages（“dplyr”）:
installation of package 'bindrcpp' had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages（“dplyr”）:
installation of package 'tibble' had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages（“dplyr”）:
installation of package 'dplyr' had non-zero exit status
```

Then I use `library(dplyr)` to check if the package has been installed, and got the message:

```
there is no package called 'dplyr'
```

Comment: What command do you use to install the packages? `install.packages()`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes

Comment: Please include all the output. For some reason the dependencies are not met automatically. If you install those by hand (`install.packages(c("glue", "rlang", "Rcpp"...))`), installation of the desired package should proceed normally.

Comment: The best way to install R packages on fedora is via the CRAN COPR repository. [Look here for how to set that up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75449961/11932936)