# When attempting to install tidyverse in R studio on fedora tidyverse's dependencies wont install

Tags: r, linux, tidyverse, fedora

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googledrive’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘gargle’, ‘googledrive’, ‘httr’, ‘ids’ are not available for package ‘googlesheets4’
* removing ‘/home/lanewhitten/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/googlesheets4’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googlesheets4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘googledrive’, ‘googlesheets4’, ‘httr’, ‘rvest’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/lanewhitten/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpxCRrL7/downloaded_packages’
```

That is the tail of my error messages. Ive already installed curl on fedora using

```
sudo dnf install curl
```

I am at a total loss as to how to resolve this and switching operating systems or running a virtual machine is not an option for me.

Comment: instead of installing `tidyverse`, try to install individual packages i.e. `install.packages('dplyr', dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: Is this the entire output? What command did you run exactly? What does `options()$repos["CRAN"]` return?

Comment: I ran install.pacakges(tidyverse)
This is what is returned by your command: "https://cran.rstudio.com/"
here is the full result https://pastebin.com/cS2EdLNa

Comment: You left out the important parts of the error from your question. The error in the full paste comes from not having the development libraries for curl installed. That's not the same as just having curl itself installed. Try `sudo dnf install libcurl-devel` as suggested by the error message itself. Same goes for `openssl-devel`

Comment: MrFlick you are a life saver thank you. Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This will make your R experience on Fedora much easier

Unfortunately, CRAN does not provide binaries for Linux. That is why, by default `install.packages()` will compile any package you install from source. Many packages require developer libraries to be installed on the system for compilation. The lack of these packages is why you got the error.

Overall, compiling packages yourself is far from ideal. All packages will take a longer time to install. Especially when you do them infrequently, updates will take an eternity. Also, finding out which system developer packages to install alongside can be time consuming as well, particularly for beginners.

Luckily, there is a COPR repository for Fedora that provides up-to-date binaries for *all* CRAN packages. All you have to do is run these few lines in the system terminal (not R console):

```bash
sudo dnf install 'dnf-command(copr)'
sudo dnf copr enable iucar/cran
sudo dnf install R-CoprManager
```

Afterwards `install.packages()` in R will install the desired packages through the system package manager. This also means that you will receive R package updates whenever you run `dnf update` or update the system with your desktop environments software management GUI.

You can find [further documentation about this on the CRAN website](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/fedora/).

Answer (score 5):

The development packages which are not specified in the error message need to be installed

```
sudo dnf install libcurl-devel
sudo dnf install openssl-devel 

then do install.packages("tidyverse")
```

Comment: Just to be crystal clear, the first two commands go in the terminal... then in the rstudio console we can do `install.packages("tidyverse")`